# Inverted y axis and nasted foor loop

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

I am writing a program that generates a fractal of a polynomial functions. To print out the result, I am using the given loop:

```
double xmin = xcenter - sizex/2;
double ymin = ycenter -  sizey/2;
double width = sizex;
double height = sizey;

for(int i=0; i < M; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < N; j++){

            double a = xmin + i * width/M;
            double b = ymin + j * height/N;

            Complex z = new Complex(a, b);
            // Call of the method that return me a color c
            pic.set(i, j, c);
        }
}
```

The pic object is a object of a class Picture and the method set sets the color of the pixel i, j to be c (everything is correct with this class).

I want the top right to have coordinates (xcenter + sizex/2 , ycenter + sizey/2)

Calling this function to a complex functions with roots in 0,0 and 3,3, this is what I get when xcenter=ycenter=0 and sizex = sizey = 6

[image]

you can check that the center point it darker (it is 0,0) and the other darker point should be at top right ( it should be 3,3) but it is on (3, -3). Calling this method to the root (-3, -3), I can check that the y axes is also inverted.

This is the last points calculated by my function and  the root to where it converges is bellow it (as you can see, the method is correct)

2.991428571428571 + 2.9485714285714284i:

3.0 + 3.0i

2.991428571428571 + 2.9571428571428573i: 5

3.0 + 3.0i

2.991428571428571 + 2.9657142857142853i: 4

3.0 + 3.0i

2.991428571428571 + 2.974285714285714i: 4

3.0 + 3.0i

2.991428571428571 + 2.982857142857143i: 4

3.0 + 3.0i

2.991428571428571 + 2.991428571428571i: 4

What is wrong with this loop?

Comment: Which picture class are you using? Maybe the (0|0) is at the upper left corner.

Comment: No, it is on the center (the method convergence show this on the image above). Aparently, I am paiting (M,N) corner (the dimensions of the image is MxN) with the color I want to paint the up right corner.

Comment: At the end of the loop, I am paiting (i, j) = (M-1, N-1) but with the color that I wanted to paint (0, N-1)

Comment: Solved. Just changed pic.set(i, N-1-j, c).

Comment: I meant your going through the loop and `pic.set(i, j, c);` So your setting the pixels of the picture. `x : 0 <= i < M` and `y : 0 <= j < N` Where the pictures origin depends on the `Picture` class. If you are using something like [Some picture class](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/Picture.html) you can change it by just calling a function. **EDIT** ok so you could solve it also then nevermind ;)

Answer (score 0):

Computer screens and images have the top right point as (0,0) location, this is from the times of text screens, where first line first character is at the top-left position.

Thus use

```
        double a = xmin + i * width/M;
        double b = ymax - j * height/N;
```

for screen / picture location (i,j)